# How To Set Portrait Or Full Height To A Video Element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a project to capture an ID card with a camera and there's an additional guideline for that ID card, so I have to call a custom camera from my Angular.

When I use `input` with the `capture` attribute:

```
<input
  #inputCamera
  type="file"
  capture="environment"
  [accept]="state.model.allowedExtension"
  (change)="handleChange($event)"
  hidden
/>
```

I can't custom it to look like this:

[image]

So, I decide to make my own with thirdparty. But the problem is that video element always in `landscape` position, so it will looks like this:

[image]

So, **how to make it full portrait position from that video element?** Because I've been try with css but it's only working on style, when I try to capture an image, it still landscape position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried passing constraints to `getUserMedia`?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: { width: 720, height: 1280 }
})
.then(function(stream) {
  /* use the stream */
})
.catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

Comment: I'm using ngx-webcam, not my own. But I will try to build my own and try the code above. I will come back soon

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I mean your answer give me some clue to explore more about it.